# My phone starts downloading an app which is named 'Google Play' but is not the actual google play

Tags: applications, malware, downloading

My phone starts downloading an app which is named 'Google Play' when I press it's dialogue for a second it shows 'Download Manager' as the app which is downloading it. But I don't have any download manager on my phone.

It seems fishy, something isn't right with the app, it's probably a malware. Please help!

I've attached the screenshots.

[image]![image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It happens everyday at evening, between 7 and 7:30, It starts, though I cancel but it starts again until it gets completed, I'm really worried, might it be that someone is hacking my phone. Please help somebody!

Comment: "Download Manager" is the built-in download system of Android. It is available on every Android device. Apps can define download tasks that are executed by this Download Manager.

Comment: But I don't find any download manager in app manager, I've unlocked developer options.

Comment: check your google play version, let the "malware" finish it's update, check version again. If it's different version it's probably not malware but regular update (which btw cannot prevented from settings, google has full control over your phone)

Comment: Google Play triggers its own updates automatically because there's no way for users to manually update some Play-related services from the Play Store directly.